# Rspec "No route matches" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

I am attempting to test my sessions_controller in Rails 3 app with rspec, but keep coming across this error when I run rspec on my `sessions_controller_spec.rb`:

```
ActionController::RoutingError:
   No route matches {:controller=>"sessions", :action=>"create"}
```

Here are all the relevant files:

`routes.rb`

```
match 'event' => 'event#create', via: [:post]
match 'event/agenda' => 'event#agenda', via: [:get]
match 'testLogin' => 'application#test_login', via: [:get]
post 'session' => 'session#create'
```

`sessions_controller.rb`

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    #MY CODE HERE
  end
end
```

`sessions_controller_spec.rb`

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe SessionsController, :type => :controller do

  describe "POST #create" do

    context "invalid params" do
        it "returns a response with status failed if all required parameters are not passed in" do
            post "create"
            response.body.status.should eq("failed")
       end
    end
  end
end
```

If there's any other info I can provide to help let me know.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
post 'session' => 'session#create'
```

Your route definition is looking for a `SessionController`, but you have defined a `SessionsController`. Fix your route.

```
post 'session' => 'sessions#create'
```

Comment: I would even write `post 'sessions' => 'sessions#create'` which would be more rest-like.

Comment: Thank you so much!  These are the things I miss after pulling an all nighter -_-.